# Encrypting messages in python

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, cryptography

In this assignment I have, I need to encrypt messages based on given keys. The challenge is indexing the key to the alphabet and making that change replace the letters in the messages. The code I have so far is:

```
def encode(key,plaintext):

    for i in key:
        key.index(i)
    for i in plaintext:
        print(plaintext.index(i))

    alpha = ["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]




def main():

    plaintextMessages = [
        ["This is the plaintext message.",
         "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"],
        ["Let the Wookiee win!",
         "epqomxuagrdwkhnftjizlcbvys"],
        ["Baseball is 90% mental. The other half is physical.\n\t\t- Yogi Berra",
         "hnftjizlcbvysepqomxuagrdwk"],
        ["I used to think I was indecisive, but now I'm not too sure.",
         "mqncdaigyhkxflujzervptobws"],
        ["Einstein's equation 'e = mc squared' shows that mass and\n\t\tenergy are interchangeable.",
         "bludcmhojaifxrkzenpsgqtywv"] ]

    codedMessages = [
        ["Uijt jt uif dpefe nfttbhf.",
         "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"],
        ["Qnhxgomhqm gi 10% bnjd eho 90% omwlignh. - Zghe Xmy",
         "epqomxuagrdwkhnftjizlcbvys"],
        ["Ulj njxu htgcfj C'gj jgjm mjfjcgjt cx, 'Ep pej jyxj veprx rlhu\n\t\t uljw'mj tpcez jculjm'. - Mcfvw Zjmghcx",
         "hnftjizlcbvysepqomxuagrdwk"],
        ["M 2-wdme uxc yr kylc ua xykd m qxdlcde, qpv wup cul'v gmtd mlw\n\t\t vuj aue yv. - Hdeew Rdyladxc",
         "mqncdaigyhkxflujzervptobws"] ]

    for i in plaintextMessages:
        encode(i[1],i[0])


main()
```

I can get the indexes of the key, and the messages, but I'm in the dark about how to get these things to interact or affect each other.

Comment: check out, [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#ord) and its inverse [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#chr), and maybe `zip` and `dict`.

Comment: There was literally 0 attempt in actually solving the problem yourself!

Answer (score 0):

If the key is supposed to shift the plaintext by it's number (for example, b will shift it by 2), then the  `ord` and `chr` functions will help. You can loop  through the plaintext, use `ord` to find  the number of the letter, then shift it, and use `chr` to find the new letter.

For example,

```
keyAscii = ord(key[i]) - 96 #I'm assuming all keys are like the above and lowercase
textAscii = ord(plaintext[i]) + keyAscii

if((textAscii > 90 and < 97) or (textAscii > 122)):   #This part is to keep it as letters
    textAscii -= 26
```

For decoding the  encoded message, you could  just do the opposite, and subtract the ASCII value.